# Tracking objects using Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a project where I have to track the baskets of a supermarket, I would like to know if it possible to track those baskets using Bluetooth Technology. and show them in a map in real time using an android app.

Comment: Your question does not suggest that you have done any basic research - please do that - follow some examples that you find during your search, try them out and if you encounter problems/errors then you can post a more specific question.

Comment: Indoor positioning is difficult and existing solutions are typically based on the smartphone being the object that is tracked. Attaching a smartphone to each basket is probably not an option. I don't have any prices, but some Bluetooth LE beacons are quite small (e.g. RuuviTag) and maybe not very expensive. Those beacons would have to be detected by scanning devices (smartphones, custom Arduino devices etc.) placed on top of the supermarket shelves. The scanning devices would have to deliver their data (estimated distances to nearby beacons) to a phone app or a back end for trilateration.

Comment: Often the approach is that the indoor space has either Bluetooth LE beacons or WiFi devices at fixed locations and the smartphone is moving around and located based on those. You could reverse this and instead have the Bluetooth LE beacons moving around with the shopping baskets and have the smartphones (or similar devices) stay still. I'm assuming the number of shopping baskets to be much larger than the amount of the stationary devices needed, so that's why I would   put the cheaper devices into the shopping baskets. But anyway, this is all just theoretical day dreaming. Might work...or not.

Answer (score 0):

Range of bluetooth is very small. So if the distance is big bluetooth will not be an appropriate solution.

What you can do is find and program some hardware, device which have location sensor (like gps) and wifi connectivity in it, to transmit its location to the server using wifi or on lan hosted server. Then you can generate the realtime map.

**Hardware for Indoor Positioning**

https://www.infsoft.com/technology/hardware